# why my pagination link doesnt appear?

Tags: php, pagination

This is my script which i have used to paginate ,,The datas are restricted to 4 but the pagination link doesn't appear

```
<? 
require_once ('Pager/Pager.php');
$connection = mysql_connect( "localhost" , "root" , "" );
mysql_select_db( "ssit",$connection);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT dFrindName FROM tbl_friendslist", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$totalItems = $row['total'];
$pager_options = array(
'mode'       => 'Sliding',   // Sliding or Jumping mode. See below.
'perPage'    => 4,   // Total rows to show per page
'delta'      => 4,   // See below
'totalItems' => $totalItems,
);
$pager = Pager::factory($pager_options);
echo $pager->links;
list($from, $to) = $pager->getOffsetByPageId();
$from = $from - 1;
$perPage = $pager_options['perPage'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_friendslist LIMIT 5 , $perPage",$connection);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['dFrindName'].'</br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you're using doesn't have `total` defined. Try:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT dFrindName, COUNT(dFrindName) AS total FROM tbl_friendslist GROUP BY dFrindName", $connection);
```

Comment: @Jonathon the data's are limited but the link doesnt appear
ex:1 2 3 next
This doesnt appear for me

Comment: what does $row['total'] contain?

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `mysql_fetch_array` not in a loop, you only fetch the latest dataset. I think you have to use `mysql_num_rows` as total-value:

```
...
$result=mysql_query("SELECT dFrindName FROM tbl_friendslist", $connection);
$totalItems = mysql_num_rows($result);
...
```